# Ask for a word describe the following part of the sentence

Tags: word-request

Consider the following text :

> The university is going to increase the parking permit fee in order to decrease the traffic around the campus.
> I agree with this plan because last week I have a Biology class in the Science Building next to the parking lot. Someone was honking, making a lot of noise. The professor had to repeat himself several times because of distractions. It was really annoying.

Now, my question is that "I expressed my opinion on the plan by sharing ... (I am not sure, maybe *a story of my biology class*)
I am looking for a word or phrase that describes my reasoning way.

I hope I could get my point across.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we should say"...last week I **had** a **b**iology class...".  The study subject name biology is not derived from a proper noun and hence uses the lower case.

We could consider "I expressed my opinion on the plan by sharing my ordeal/bad experience related to campus traffic noise during my biology class."

Answer (score 1):

Your proposal sounds fine to me, except you need to change "of" to another preposition, and I think "from" works best: "I expressed my opinion on the plan by sharing a story *from* my biology class."